# Will adding a base class for my objects break .NET/XML deserialization?

Tags: .net, serialization

The base class will only contain methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change the version number of containing assembly then adding base class shouldn't be a problem for binary serialization and for XML it doesn't matter at all since it is very loosly coupled with actual type.

Just make sure that the base is also marked [Serializable] for binary serialization.
I've just tested and confirmed this.

Serialized the following class with Binary Formatter

```
[Serializable]
    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Got the following base64 encoded output:

> AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAEpDb25zb2xlQXBwbGljYXRpb24xLCBWZXJzaW9uPTEuMC4wLjAs
>   IEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAUBAAAAIENvbnNvbGVBcHBsaWNhdGlv
>   bjEuUHJvZ3JhbStUZXN0AQAAABU8TmFtZT5rX19CYWNraW5nRmllbGQBAgAAAAYDAAAABWhhc2FuCw==

Then added following base class for Test:

```
[Serializable]
public class Base
{
   public void Dhuz() { }
}
```

And de serialized the base64 encoded thing again successfully without problems.